# Detecting if Apache is using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo

How can a client detect if a server is using mod_rewrite?  Now I know that some mod_rewrite rules are not very obvious.  But some are,  such as "SEO Friendly Urls".  What types of behavior is impossible unless a server is running mod_rewrite?

Comment: There is no behaviour that is *entirely* impossible, but there are patterns that occur extremely rarely without mod_rewrite.

Comment: Note that there is not only one web server software.

Comment: @Gumbo♦ True,  but the vast vast majority of web servers online are Apache.  If you know of another method for some strange HTTPD i'll give you a +1.

Comment: [Almost every web server software has a similar module/feature.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine#Web_frameworks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What types of behavior is impossible unless a server is running mod_rewrite?

The real answer is "none". In theory, any URL could be formed by actual files or directories, including the classical "SEO friendly" URLs.

There is only **circumstantial evidence:**

- The best indication that I can think of is when the entire site structure consists of URLs without `.htm .php .html` file extensions:

  ```
  http://domain.com/slugs/house-warming-party
  ```

  to exclude the possibility of that URL being a directory, request

  ```
  http://domain.com/slugs/house-warming-party/index.htm
  http://domain.com/slugs/house-warming-party/index.html
  http://domain.com/slugs/house-warming-party/index.php
  http://domain.com/slugs/house-warming-party/index.asp
  ... whatever other extensions there are .....
  ```

  if those requests all **fail**, it is very likely that the site is using mod_rewrite. However if they succeed, as @Gumbo says, it could also be the `MultiViews` option fixing the request. Either way, this is **nowhere** near safe!
- Depending on what your use case is, you could also try to deduct things from the CMS used on the site. Wordpress with mod_rewrite turned on will show a different URL structure than with it turned off. The same holds true for most other CMSes. But of course, this is also a highly imperfect approach.
- The use of HTML resources **with** a .html/.htm/.php ending would point slightly against the use of mod_rewrite, but you can never be sure.
- The use of the PATHINFO variable (also known as poor man's mod_rewrite) would point somewhat strongly against the use of mod_rewrite:

  ```
  http://example.com/index.php/slugs/house-warming-party
  ```

In conclusion, `mod_rewrite` (like most URL-rewriting tools) is supposed to be a module transparent to the outside world. I know of no sure-fire way to detect it from outside, and there may well be none.

Comment: MultiViews allows the same behavior.